# Disable asset fingerprinting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to disable asset fingerprinting by placing the following line in my config/environments/production.rb:

```
  config.assets.digest = false
```

However, rails isn't honoring this and still compiling assets with a fingerprint in public/assets/:

```
bear-e1d6322cce5569e1c88e51d726af8f49.jpg
```

Why is rails ignoring this?
Follow up question: if rails is stubborn about fingerprinting assets, why won't it change the name of the asset in the html.erb file so that the browser will know the right name of the file to request?

Comment: In [production](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) there is no automatic precompiling, you should run `rake assets:precompile` so that the assets will be available as static files, and will be provided directly as static files.

Comment: the rake task should be written this way `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Good point, forgot to mention I'm deploying with Capistrano - so that takes care of the pre-compilation command. In any case, that's not the issue: the issue is that sprockets is fingerprinting the assets though I have told it not to.

Comment: so which version of rails are you using exatly? 3, 4?

Comment: also this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11403

Comment: How can tell which version I'm running on server? I issued: rails -v then I receive: "The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:"

Comment: config.assets.compile was set to false, which invalidates config.assets.digest, but why is that? Assuming I'm on Rails 4, how do I prevent fingerprinting?

Comment: You can check the version of Rails in your `Gemfile.lock` usually.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on rails (= 4.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

For webpacker below to v4, (webpack 3),
I add three things:

- gem 'non-stupid-digest-assets' to remove fingerprint on sprocket assets compiled
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/non-digest-webpack-plugin, to disable fingerprint for js paths, compiled by webpack
- And I redefine extract text plugin, without fingerprint for css files:

  ```
  // in config/webpack/custom.js file
  const webpack = require('webpack')
  const NonDigestPlugin = require('non-digest-webpack-plugin')
  const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

  module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    plugins: [
      new NonDigestPlugin(),
      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    ]
  }
  ```

And export it on environment:

```
// In config/webpack/environment.js
const customConfig = require('./custom')

environment.config.merge(customConfig)
module.exports = environment
```

Answer (score -3):

The answer is here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline

To avoid pre-compilation of assets (and fingerprinting) just place assets in public/ and NOT in app/assets